# Ionic 3 Unable to fix maxlength for prompt input of alert controller

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Im used my mobile application for ionic-3 I have some small issue, I  want to set the max length dynamically, I tried but not work  that  Unable to fix `max length` for `prompt input of alert controller`  I want to know how to do that dynamically,   and Im tried to used  `max:'4',
          type:'number',`  but not work ,

Thanks

```
 doPrompt() {
        let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Add your digit code',
          message: "",
          inputs: [
            { 

             type:'number',
              name: 'title',


           placeholder: '* * * *',
              max:'4',
            },
          ],
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Cancel',
              handler: data => {
                console.log('Cancel clicked');
              }
            },
            {
              text: 'Save',
              handler: data => {
                console.log('Saved clicked');
              }
            }
          ]
        });
        prompt.present();
      }
    }
```

Comment: I think there is no way to do it. `Max` and `Min` in this case is max value and min value of input

Comment: yeah, ionic team not provided this option, finally Im gone a model option

Answer (score 0):

Although it's and old post it might help someone with the same issue.
in Ionic 5, you can use the `attributes` property under `inputs` to pass Input HTML Attributes

```
alertCtrl.create({
  message: 'Hello',
  inputs: [{
    type: 'text',
    name: 'textInput',
    cssClass: 'custom-class',
    attributes: {
      maxLength: 4,
      inputmode: 'numeric'
    }
  }],
  buttons: [{
    text: 'OK',
    handler: (inputData) => {
      if (inputData?.textInput) {
        console.log('Data: ', inputData?.textInput);
      }
    }
  }]
}).then(alrt => alrt.present());
```

check the Ionic [AlertAttributes docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert#alertattributes) (although it doesnt go to details on this)

Update: It works with `type: 'text'`. It doesn't work with `type: 'number'`